# How to work with CALayer: Trying to draw a Layer in my Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, warnings, calayer

I am trying to add a layer(CALayer/CGLayer) to my application. So i googled for that and tried.  When i am trying to create a CALayer using the following code

```
-(void) awakeFromNib{
    CALayer *layer =[CALayer layer];
}
```

But it is showing some warning when compiling.[Warning: No +'layer' method found]

I add the framework QuartzCore.framework and my interface is inheriting from NSObject.

If it is possible to add a CGLayer to my View, tell me how?
I read the Guide "drawingWithQurtz2D" but i didn't get anything.

[SORRY FOR MY POOR ENGLISH]

Point out my mistake, before mentioning any guide to read [I have less time].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the QuartzCore headers into your .m file.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: #import "T_CALayer.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@implementation T_CALayer

-(void) awakeFromNib{
 CALayer *layer =[CALayer layer];
}

@end
That didn't worked.

Comment: Can anyone give a simple example with a  colored square in a View.